# Синхронизация Netbeans с FTP

Tags: ftp, netbeans

Там, где я работаю, люди редактируют исходиники прямо на сервере по ftp с самого начала разработки (кстати, адекватно ли это). А среда разработки netbeans синхронизируется с ftp либо только когда я нажму "Загрузить" на проекте, а до этого момента netbeans хранит старую копию файла, и может получиться так, что кто-то внес изменения в файл, а я решив, что не было изменений, просто перезаписал файл на сервере, тем самым откатив его до моей локальной версии. Сейчас я перед редактированием любого файла жму на нем "загрузить", чтобы он синхронизировался с ftp, а только потом редактирую. Собственно вопрос в том, как мне заставить netbeans синхронизировать файл при каждом его открытии?

Comment: А ведь есть масса систем управления версиями. От древних примитивов типа rcs до ... (ну знатоки поставят более подходящее им по вкусу).

Comment: есть то они есть, но они говорят что в случае когда над сайтом работают 3 человека система контроля версий забирает много времени + теряется время при переносе сайта на хостинг

Comment: А когда забирает много времени, эта система только угрожает пистолетом или делает предупредительные выстрелы в воздух?

Answer (score 4):

Синхронизация с ftp - костыль, а не решение задачи.
Договоритесь с другими программистами и используйте системы контроля версий (git, hg и другие). 
Один день на обучение и обкатку на проекте — сотни сэкономленных часов и нервных клеток при деплое.

Comment: я там один программист =), со мной над сайтом работают еще 2 веб технолога(в простонародье верстальщик с некоторыми знаниями javascript), дайте линки что почитать чтобы реально либо сократить время разработки либо оставить его таким-же в случае перехода на git

Comment: Ну хоть и костыль, но всё же. Система управления версиями установленная сепаратно/локально скажет о том, сам ошибков налепил или друзья помогли.

Comment: кстати, NetBeans можно связать с гитом :) Во время ежемесячного пересмотра кода мы часто смотрим кто автор той или иной строчки )